# meteor easy-search server-side filtering

Tags: mongodb, search, meteor, elasticsearch

I have a collection called "Contacts", where each document has authorId. I want the user to server-side search the collection (for performance purpose, so I'm using the MongoDB engine), but only returns contacts that have the same authorId as the user. It seems like the permission just either allows or denies access to the entire collection. Is there a way to implement server-side filtering?

Thanks

Comment: Are you actually wanting to query `Contacts` for a string or some value and then filter by `userId` or are you merely trying to publish all `Contacts` whose `authorId` is `Meteor.userId()`?

Comment: have you published all the contacts needed?

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear. I was talking about the easy-search permission here: http://matteodem.github.io/meteor-easy-search/docs/core/

 I wasn't talking about the meteor permission.

Comment: Also, this has nothing to do with publication, because I'm using server-side search.

Answer (score 0):

Add Mongo selectors to the query option.

ex:

```
EasySearch.createSearchIndex('contactsIndex', {
  'collection': Contacts,
  },
  'query': function(searchString) {
     var query = EasySearch.getSearcher(this.use).defaultQuery(this, searchString);
     query.authorId = {$in: Meteor.userId}
     return query;
   }
});
```

Comment: I have an example app of easy search. https://github.com/DylanKojiCheslin/adamant-octo-kidney

Comment: I think this method is not secured because client side can modify Meteor.userId to be anything and have access to other authors's contacts. Also, I'm using the MongoDB engine so search is carried out on the entire collection on server-side.

Comment: Meteor.users.deny({  
      update: function() {
        return true;
      }
    });

Comment: Josh Owens recommends this in http://joshowens.me/the-curious-case-of-the-unknowing-leaky-meteor-security/

Comment: there is no server limitation for the permission in easy search. You could have the function that is returned permission be a Meteor.method that uses the user conformation pattern described in the "Verify your user input" section of joshowens.me/meteor-security-201

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the proper way to do this with the permission option.

http://matteodem.github.io/meteor-easy-search/docs/core/

Basically, I would pass the authorId in the selectors as a filter and verify in the permission that the authorId is the same as the current userId.

I have not verified if the permission is actually carried out in the server. But it would be very wrong for a permission check to be done on client side.